# Which language is used in this code

Tags: php, content-management-system, smarty

I have a problem with my CMS system. I have code like this:

```
{if}
   {$hello}
{/if}
```

Could you tell me which language is used to write this code?

Answer (score 6):

It looks like PHP with the Smarty template engine:

http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.syntax.functions.tpl

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like Smarty syntax, which would be PHP.

[Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.if.tpl)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [Smarty template engine](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.basic.syntax.tpl).